# ID ranges and Incrementing

Tags: c#, sql-server

There is a `PilotID` field in the database that starts at `1` and can go up to `9999`. Now they want me to add 2 more pilot types.
One with id's starting at `10,000` and the other starting at `20,000`.

They all need to share the `PilotID` field. My problem is that once I create a pilot with the highest ID, when I try to create a new one it just wants to increment on the highest id in the database. Here is an example of one case. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
int newpilotID = 0;
int pecID = 10000;
int highSeaID = 20000;

 //checking for PEC provider
if (Session["Role"].ToString().Equals("Provider") && (Session["ProviderID"].ToString().Equals("25")))      
{
    sqlCN.Open();
    qlCOM = new SqlCommand("select f_name from t_Provider where f_Active=1 and f_ProviderID = 25 order by f_name", sqlCN);
    sqlDR = sqlCOM.ExecuteReader();
    Employer.Items.Clear();
    while (sqlDR.Read())
    {
        Employer.Items.Add(sqlDR.GetString(0));
    }
    sqlDR.Close();
    Employer.Items[0].Selected = true;

    sqlCOM = new SqlCommand("select f_PilotID from t_Pilot", sqlCN);
    sqlDR = sqlCOM.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlDR.Read())
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(sqlDR.GetString(0)) > pecID) 
        {
            pecID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDR.GetString(0));
        }
    }
    sqlDR.Close();

    pecID++;
    PilotID.Text = pecID.ToString();
```

Comment: Is this for MS SQL Server? Is there anything specific only to C# 4.0?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Nothing specific. I am trying to figure out how to find the highest number for each case and then increment from there for the correct type depending on the providerId in session.

Comment: Is your general question how to create an id that is within a given range?

Comment: I think it is a bad idea to put semantics in an ID. Suppose the first provider provides more than 10000 pilots? Normaly that pilot would get Id 10000, but that range has been assigned to another provider. Maybe it isn't a problem now but it will realy bite you if the software lasts in production for years.

Comment: Better add a Pilot-type field to the database and leave the ID a simple autoincrement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply asking the database for the current highest number for a case and then increment that result with 1?

```
select max(id) from mytable where id between 1 and 9999
```

Comment: Thank your for the replies! I think your idea will work @souplex

Comment: Assuming you are in control of creating the unique id values yourself and not using auto incrementing values, I see no issue. Pleun's answer is a much more robust solution to your problem If this is not working for you, I suggest exploring that solution.